# Order of the stars in this recursion function

Tags: c, function, loops, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printPattern(int n);
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nType the number of lines you want to print: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printPattern(n);
    return 0;
}

void printPattern(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    printPattern(n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Here, when I run the program, it works without showing any error. But my question is why does it prints the output in a pyramid shape? I mean it's not that I don't want it to but I wanna know why. I am a complete beginner and I'm learning to code all by myself so I wanna know why and how things work. Thank you.

Comment: step through the code line by line in a debugger

Comment: Seriously, do what @OldProgrammer suggests!

Comment: It's always best to phrase your question in such a way that you call attention to both your _expected_ results and your _actual_ results.  What are you expecting this code will do?

Answer (score 1):

Because it goes

```
printPattern(4)
    printPattern(3)
        printPattern(2)
            printPattern(1)
                printPattern(0)
                print newline
            print * and newline
        print ** and newline
    print *** and newline
print **** and newline
```